# Quality control in DTS to AAC(stereo) conversion using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, audio-quality

I am trying to convert a DTS stream to AAC(stereo) using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv"  
-c:v copy  
-c:a aac -q:a 2 -ac 2 -ar 48000  
  "output.mp4"
```

[ffmpeg version : 3.4.8]

Here q:a 2 controls the output bitrate or quality of the audio stream (VBR). In FFmpeg docs its effective range is given as 0.1-2 where 2 is the best quality. But I have tried increasing this number up to 5 or 6 and the bitrate of output stream keeps increasing.

So I want to know the best possible way to convert the DTS   stream to AAC stream with the highest quality. For example, is there a number **n**  such that q:**n** will set the highest quality conversion?

Thanks.

Comment: The native AAC encoder goes upto ~260 kbps. Set it usising bitrate.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan  I will try it using bitrate.